# iOS - multipart/form-data post

Tags: ios, iphone, http-headers, nsurlconnection, multipartform-data

I am developing an iOS app which is using multipart/form_data. But I've got stuck on it. 
What I have is data structure from Http Analyzer 7.

[Raw stream from Http Analyzer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cw4bG.png)

I've googled and tried a lot to accomplish this in iOS app but didn't get any chance of success.

Could someone help me?

Here is what I've tried.

```
- (void)signUpOnWeb:(NSString *)strStrToken {

NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http//www.karelboele.com/forms/signups"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:10];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"www.karelboele.com" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Host"];
[request setValue:@"keep-alive" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Connection"];
[request setValue:@"text/javascript" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
[request setValue:@"http://www.karelboele.com/app" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Referer"];
[request setValue:@"gzip, deflate" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"];
[request setValue:@"en-US,en;q=0.5" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Language"];
[request setValue:@"XMLHttpRequest" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Requested-With"];


NSDictionary *params = @{@"authenticity_token" : strStrToken, @"page_id" : @"406", @"return_to" : @"http://www.karelboele.com/app", @"email_address" : @"", @"signup[first_name]" : @"Vuhar", @"signup[last_name]" : @"Mamedov", @"signup[email]" : @"vuharmamedov@gmail.com", @"signup[born_at_chronic]" : @"10/12/1985", @"signup[email_opt_in]" : @"0", @"signup[email_opt_in]" : @"1", @"signup[mobile_number]" : @"123456789", @"signup[mobile_opt_in]" : @"0", @"signup[mobile_opt_in]" : @"1", @"signup[phone_number]" : @"123456789", @"signup[submitted_address]" : @"1, kyiv, kyiv, kyiv, 130000", @"signup[country_code]" : @"UA", @"signup[is_volunteer]" : @"0", @"signup[activity_is_private]" : @"0", @"commit" : @"Accept Terms and Conditions and submit"};


NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------1388669659902";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];

[request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];


NSData *httpBody = [self createBodyWithBoundary:params boundary:(NSString*)boundary];


[request setHTTPBody:httpBody];


NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)[httpBody length]];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
 {

     NSHTTPURLResponse *responseCode = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;

     if([responseCode statusCode] != 200){
         NSLog(@"Error getting HTTP status code %li", (long)[responseCode statusCode]);

     }

     else {

         NSString* htmlResponse = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
     }
 }];
```

}

```
- (NSData *)createBodyWithBoundary:(NSDictionary *)parameters boundary:(NSString*)boundary {
NSMutableData *httpBody = [NSMutableData data];

// add params (all params are strings)

[parameters enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *parameterKey, NSString *parameterValue, BOOL *stop) {
    [httpBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [httpBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", parameterKey] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [httpBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", parameterValue] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}];

[httpBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

return httpBody;
```

}

I am not too sure what mistake I made.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Vuhar

Comment: first question: What error/unexpected behaviour do you get? "I´ve got stuck on" is a little broad.

Comment: error NSURLError * domain: @"NSURLErrorDomain" - code: 18446744073709550614 0x00007ffe83d9c960

Comment: Just solved my problem using AFNetworking. Excellent!

Answer (score -1):

Use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) multipart form data. It will save your time and also you can track how much data is uploaded or even your request failed in failure block.